# Route all sub-locations to index.php with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'd like to parse the URL in my php script, therefor I need everything from a specific location to route to index.php.

However, I can only see the specific php file when navigating directly to the file.

---

Example, the requests;

1. mycomain.ext/api
2. mycomain.ext/api/user
3. mycomain.ext/api/user/19
4. mycomain.ext/api/user/19/detail

should all route to `api/index.php`

---

Current config:

```
 location /api {
    root /usr/share/nginx/php/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it points to `/index.php` and not to `/api/index.php` as intended. Just change your try_files to `try_files /api/index.php?$args =404;`. And have a dedicated `/api/index.php` location where you forward the request to your php-fpm.

---

Native there is no `$query_string` variable, there is only the `$args` variable to pass all arguments. The variable `$request_uri` should not be used, only if it is encoded correctly. Your php script should use `explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2)[0]` to handle the correct requests.